# SQL Selecting the earliest date from many within a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I am working in MS SQL Server Management Studio. I have created a view keyed on patientId, each patient/row has 12 associated dates. Is there a way in SQL that I can find the min and max dates for each row?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Add Sample data and expected output

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server+greatest-n-per-group)

Comment: Try reading about group by, min, max and joins

Comment: Are you asking about calculating min/max of several fields in a **single** row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "unpivot". Check the example below:

```
CREATE TABLE dates
    (
      number INT PRIMARY KEY ,
      date1 DATETIME ,
      date2 DATETIME ,
      date3 DATETIME
    )

INSERT  INTO dates
VALUES  ( 1, '1/1/2018', '2/4/2018', '3/1/2018')
INSERT  INTO dates
VALUES  ( 2, '1/2/2018', '2/3/2018', '3/3/2018')
INSERT  INTO dates
VALUES  ( 3, '1/3/2018', '2/2/2018', '3/2/2018')
INSERT  INTO dates
VALUES  ( 4, '1/4/2018', '2/1/2018', '3/4/2018')
GO

SELECT  number ,
        MIN(dDate) mindate,
        MAX(dDate) maxDate 
FROM    dates UNPIVOT ( dDate FOR nDate IN ( Date1, Date2,Date3 ) ) as u
GROUP BY number 
GO
```

Comment: As a note, the versions using `apply` and subqueries should have better performance.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this using `cross apply`:

```
select t.*, v.mind, v.maxd
from t cross apply
     (select min(v.d) as mind, max(v.d) as maxd
      from (values (d1), (d2), (d3), (d4), (d5), (d6), (d7), (d8), (d9), (d10), (d11), (d12)
           ) v(d)
     ) v;
```

Note that `min()` and `max()` ignore `NULL` values.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
create table MyDates
(
    ID int,
    D1 datetime,
    D2 datetime,
    D3 datetime
)

insert  MyDates(ID, D1, D2, D3)
values  (1, '19000101', '19720506', '20060204'),
        (2, '20170624', '20180821', '20180901'),
        (3, '19820202', '19840721', '19851231')

select  *,
        (select min(v) from (values(D1), (D2), (D3)) t(v)) [Min],
        (select max(v) from (values(D1), (D2), (D3)) t(v)) [Max]
from MyDates
```

Comment: nice alternative way, liked it. Thanks for sharing